# C: Printing the longest word in a string and its length

Tags: c

I'm beginning with C language and I'm learning it through a platform that checks automatically the code I write (e.g., it gives me some task and after uploading the code it checks whether what I wrote gives meaningful results).

So far all has been working fine, but I'm stuck with one problem that, to my eye I've solved, but after uploading the code and running it, an error occurs that I frankly don't understand.

**TASK:** Print the longest word in a sentence, and its length.

**My Attempt:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[80], word[80];
    fgets(str, 80, stdin);

    char *token;

    //tokenizing array str
    token = strtok(str, " ");


    while( token != NULL )
    {
        if(strlen(word) < strlen(token) )
        {
            strcpy(word, token);
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, " ");

    }

    printf("%s %d", word, strlen(word));




    return 0;

}
```

For instance if one writes

```
hello my name is jacksparrowjunior goodbye
```

one gets

```
jacksparrowjunior 17
```

And the error is this:

```
TEST
PASSED
==20760== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20760==    at 0x4006B9: main (004799.c:18)
==20760==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==20760==    at 0x400660: main (004799.c:6)
==20760== 
==20760== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20760==    at 0x4006E5: main (004799.c:18)
==20760==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==20760==    at 0x400660: main (004799.c:6)
==20760==
```

The other thing I noticed, is that if I change

```
char str[80], word[80];
        fgets(str, 80, stdin);
```

to

```
char str[1000], word[1000];
        fgets(str,1000, stdin);
```

I get an error after running the program in my computer.

Comment: The contents of `word` are initially undefined, since you don't initialize this buffer. Thus, doing a `strlen` on an uninitialized buffer results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the given Data and without testing I would guess you should initialize str and word to ""

```
[...]
char str[80] = "";
char word[80] = "";
fgets(str, 80, stdin);
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is both helpful and arcane.  Notice the reference to a Conditional and an uninitialized.  So you should go and look at conditions ("if tests") in your code.

The next lines in the error give clues where to look: lines 18 and 6.